# Plotting a Geodataframe using naturalearth_lowres

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a Geodataframe containing geometry points related to fire incidents. I have plotted them on the world's map, using naturalearth_lowres dataset:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.plot(ax=world.plot (figsize=(25,10)), marker='.', color='black')
```

I would like to do the same with an interactive map this time, but when I replace "plot" with "explore" it gives me an error:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.explore(ax=world.plot (figsize=(25,10)), marker='.', color='black')

TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'marker'
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing **matplotlib** and **folium**. They are separate libraries to be used independently.

- `plot()` uses **matplotlib**
- `explore()` uses **folium**

Have used earthquakes instead of fires for purpose of code.  Below will plot lowres earth and earthquake plots on single **folium** map.

```
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf = gpd.read_file("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_week.geojson")
m = world.explore()
gdf.explore(m=m, color="black")
```